# How to simply requeue a RabbitMQ message in case of code exception with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, java-11

I would like to learn an easy way to requeue a RabbitMQ if an exception is thrown in an SpringBoot application.

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = TRANSACTION_171_REQUEST_QUEUE, errorHandler="receiverExceptionHandler")
public void listen171RequestsQueue(Transaction171Request request) {
   try {
        Transaction171Response response = null;
        send171Response("OK", request.getNumeroFormularioRenach());
    } catch (Exception e){
        //Requeue message
    }
}
```

My code behaviour is to consume a message and take it out of the queue independing of what it happens. I would like to requeue message in RabbitMQ if an exception is thrown.

Could you help me?

I am working in a SpringBoot application with Java 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ's default behavior is to requeue when there is an unhandled exception. In your case, you could remove the try..catch block or in the catch block just re-throw the exception.